# How to get the value out of a GWT HTML element?

Tags: java, html, dom, gwt, slider

my problem is, that there are now slider elements inside GWT, so i tryed using an HTML element to work araound that problem:

```
HTML slider = new HTML(
                "<input type=\"range\" name=\"historyRange\" min=\"-960\" max=\"960\" value=\"0\" class=\"slider\" id=\"counter\" oninput=\"this.form.historyRange.value=this.value\" />"
            );
```

So now i only needed the value out of that slider. I tried

```
String test = DOM.getElementAttribute(slider.getElement(), "value");
```

and the same with StyleAttribute, but no luck. I tried to get the Element by ID with

```
String test = Document.get().getElementById("counter").getAttribute("value");
```

but no luck either.

I'm out of ideas here, how i can make this thing work.

Kiouri.sliderbar and Smart GWT are no options for my problem.

(termurin-11 and JetBrains GWT Plugin 221.5080.56)

Answer (score 1):

GWT does not directly support `<input type='range' />` elements, but it has a generic `<input />` element support: [InputElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/InputElement.html).

You can *cast* your slider element to an InputElement this way:

```
InputElement input = InputElement.as(Document.get().getElementById("counter"));
```

To get the value just call:

```
input.getValue();
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it's not working, since getValue only works for "text", "file" or "password" types, not range types.

Comment: @ShadowClone I've tried (GWT 2.7) and it worked fine.

Comment: And i tried it today again, does not work. Nullpointer exception... Remeber, it must be java 11... (termurin-11)